# How can I load a static font file for use with PIL in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to load a static font file using both `settings.STATIC_URL` and plain string. In my app I have a folder named /static. and my font's path is /static/fonts/kberry.ttf

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(path_to_static, 12)
```

What should `path_to_static` be? I've literally tried everything and all I get is `IOError`.

Answer (score 0):

> “I've literally tried everything”

*Literally* everything? Every possible combination of characters that will fit into memory? I’m not sure what you think we can do then :)

But just in case, I’m guessing `path_to_static` needs to be the full local filesystem path to the font file (rather than a web URL where the file can be found, which is what `STATIC_URL` would contain).

In my settings file, I declare a `SITE_ROOT` variable, like this:

```
import os

SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

That sets `SITE_ROOT` to the full path of the Django project folder.

If your static folder containing the font file is in the root of your project folder, then you should be able to get its path like this:

```
import os, settings

path_to_static = os.path.join(settings.SITE_ROOT, 'static/fonts/kberry.ttf')
```